# what wrong in line 26 that im getting an error

Tags: networking, syntax, pool, dhcp

[the last failover-dhcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iRGr.png)

I tried rewriting it and asking chatgpt for help and everything it still wouldn't show. The error comes off as missing semicolon , eol and that's it but when I checked everything is perfect. But the same error keeps popping up